# Uploading multiple files to SharePoint

Tags: python-3.x, sharepoint

I figured out how to upload one file to SharePoint but my end goal is to be able to select files with tkinter edit their metadata and upload them. But I can't seem to figure out how to upload multiple files.

```
with open( file_name, 'rb') as file_input:
try:
    response = session.post(
        url=base_path + "/sites/" + site_name + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + doc_library + "')/Files/add(url='"
        + file_name + "',overwrite=true)",
        data=file_input)
    print(Fore.GREEN + "File(s) uploaded successfully")
except Exception as err:
    print(Fore.RED + "Some error occurred: " + str(err))
```

Comment: how do you get `file_name`, do you use `filedialog` then use `filedialog.askopenfilenames`. Check [here](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/dialog.html#tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilenames)

Comment: As of right now I just have file_name = "examplefile.txt".

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with it the next day here is what ended up working for me. This will upload all the files in the directory that the file is in.

```
for filename in os.listdir():
with open(os.path.join(filename), 'rb') as file_input:
    try:
        response = session.post(
            url=base_path + "/sites/" + site_name + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + doc_library + "')/Files/add(url='"
            + filename + "',overwrite=true)",
            data=file_input)
        print(Fore.GREEN + "File(s) uploaded successfully")
    except Exception as err:
        print(Fore.RED + "Some error occurred: " + str(err))
```